# How to determine a status from two different columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

I am trying to determine a "Complete" or "Incomplete" value in my query but I need to reference two different columns to determine.

For example - I have a shipment that has 4 events. In the database, I have the following columns.

'cs_event_count' and 'cs_completed'

Event count tells me the total # of events and Completed tells me how many of those events have been completed.

I want my query to say something like the following

If 'Event count' value equals 'Completed' value then "COMPLETE"
If 'Event count' does not match 'Completed' value then "INCOMPLETE"

I am also bringing in data from other tables. Here is my query

Here is a sample of my query

```
  select dba.disp_ship.ds_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_origin_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_findest_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_billto_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_bill_charge,
dba.disp_ship.ds_status, dba.disp_ship.ds_bill_date, dba.disp_ship.ds_ship_date, dba.disp_ship.ds_ship_type, dba.disp_ship.movecode, 
dba.companies.co_id, dba.companies.co_name, dba.current_shipments.cs_id, dba.current_shipments.cs_event_count, dba.current_shipments.cs_routed, dba.current_shipments.cs_assigned, dba.current_shipments.cs_completed,
(CASE ds_status WHEN 'A' THEN 'TEMPLATE'
WHEN 'C' THEN 'CANCELLED'
WHEN 'D' THEN 'DECLINED'
WHEN 'E' THEN 'QUOTED'
WHEN 'F' THEN 'OFFERED' 
WHEN 'H' THEN 'PENDING'
WHEN 'K' THEN 'OPEN'
WHEN 'N' THEN 'AUTHORIZED'
WHEN 'Q' THEN 'AUDIT REQUIRED'
WHEN 'T' THEN 'AUDITED'
WHEN 'W' THEN 'BILLED' 
END) AS 'BILLING STATUS',
(CASE ds_ship_type WHEN '2201' THEN 'MONTREAL'
WHEN '2202' THEN 'DRYVAN'
WHEN '2203' THEN 'BROKERAGE'
WHEN '2204' THEN 'OLD BROKERAGE (NO GOOD)'
WHEN '2205' THEN 'LIFTING'
WHEN '2206' THEN 'WAREHOUSE'
END) AS 'DIVISION'
from dba.disp_ship
inner join dba.companies ON dba.disp_ship.ds_billto_id=dba.companies.co_id
inner join dba.current_shipments ON dba.disp_ship.ds_id=DBA.current_shipments.cs_id
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and decide on the database tag.

Comment: Why isn't there a table of statuses? And a table of ship_types?

Comment: not sure what the query has to do with the question but fwiw ... the query shows that you know about the `case` statement so why not implement the desired logic in a `case` statement? `case when event_count=completed then 'COMPLETE' else 'INCOMPLETE' end` (format may need to change based on actual RDBMS in use)

Comment: @markp-fuso Scarier still, the code copied into the question already includes `CASE` expressions *(they're not statements)*.  The OP apparently was unable to extrapolate...

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I am ok with SQL but not a power user. I did not know I can use CASE to calculate this value. I added it to my query and it worked! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using a `CASE` expression, as per the code included in your question?

```
CASE WHEN dba.current_shipments.cs_event_count = dba.current_shipments.cs_completed
     THEN   'COMPLETE'
     ELSE 'INCOMPLETE'
END
  AS Status
```